# Query result does not return values in decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why does the following query not returning values in decimal? I wanted the CustRating and Rating Difference column to return the values in decimal.

```
SELECT 
     a.CustNo AS CustNo,
     a.CustRating AS CustomerRate,
     a.RatingDate AS RatingDate,
     (a.CustRating-b.CustRating) AS [Rating Difference]
FROM 
     MasterTable a
          JOIN MasterTable b ON b.CustNo = a.CustNo
ORDER BY 
     CustNo
```

This is the original table [MasterTable]

```
CustNo  CustRating  RatingDate
101AAA  0.000500000 "2016-01-08 00:00:00.000"
101AAA  0.000000750 "2016-01-12 00:00:00.000"
101AAA  0.000000550 "2016-01-22 00:00:00.000"
101AAA  0.000000000 "2016-01-27 00:00:00.000"
```

This is the query result:

```
CustNo  CustRating  RatingDate                  Rating Difference
101AAA  0           "2016-01-08 00:00:00.000"   0
101AAA  0           "2016-01-12 00:00:00.000"   0
101AAA  0           "2016-01-22 00:00:00.000"   0
101AAA  0           "2016-01-27 00:00:00.000"   0
```

Comment: The second column you select is CustomerRate, but the result's second column is CustRating...

Comment: Why are you are joining the table against itself on CustNo and nothing else?

Comment: This query will return 16 rows (in fact it should fail with an ambigous colum error), but only 4 of them will show a zero difference. Please show the actual query and add the table DDL.

Comment: @crowne the objective here is to calculate the difference in customer rating row by row based on customer no. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: But (b) will return all ratings, as well as a copy of (a) itself. Surely you would want (b) to return only the rating immediately prior to (a). It looks like you need to apply some sort of windowing or ranking technique.

Answer (score 2):

I assume your column is an integer? You can easily use convert for this.

```
CONVERT(decimal(9,2), a.CustRating) AS CustomerRate,
CONVERT(decimal(9,2), a.CustRating - b.CustRating) as RatingDifference
```

Comment: The data shows `0.000000750`, how can this be an integer?

Comment: lol. Well it is pretty vague for sure. It shows 0 in the other columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take total 10 digit and 3 digit after decimal point

```
SELECT a.CustNo AS CustNo ,
       CAST(a.CustRating as decimal(10,3)) AS CustomerRate,
       a.RatingDate AS RatingDate,
       CAST((a.CustRating-b.CustRating) as decimal(10,3)) AS [Rating Difference]
FROM MasterTable a
JOIN MasterTable b
ON b.CustNo = a.CustNo
ORDER BY CustNo
```